State feedback control with some states left uncontrolled
In short
I have a linear MIMO system:
$$\dot{\textbf{x}}=\textbf{Ax}+\textbf{Bu}$$
Is it possible to use state feedback control in some way so that some states are left uncontrolled?
A bit more elaboration
In my derivation, the state vector turned out to be dependent on the derivative of a  variable originally treated as an input. To avoid having to recalculate the system matrix (and the state feedback gain) in every iteration, I had to make this value part of the state. However, I do not want to control this value directly with a reference signal, I only care about the other states. The value of this variable is crucial however, because (as I mentioned) every part of the state vector is deeply influenced by it.
Can state feedback control used in such a way that it leaves this part of the state uninfluenced by any reference signal of mine and is set optimally to achieve control of the other parts of the state vector?
Even more specifics
Some specifics to aid the picture: the system describes an RC car performing a task, that has front and rear wheel steering. Originally I planned to ignore the dynamics of the steering servos and treat the steering angles as the inputs. However, the differential equations are dependent on the derivatives of these angles, so I couldn't avoid having to deal with the dynamics of the steering servos. This makes it necessary to have the steering angles as states and have some other variables as inputs that influence the angles. I don't want to directly control the steering angles however, I only care about the other states (so that the car performs its task). I wouldn't even know the appropriate reference signal for the angles, for the whole point of the state feedback is to set these angles appropriately.

"and is set optimally to achieve control" Do you intend to do this with control? It sounds a bit like you want to decouple some states but I think you should really give a clear example of your use case, i.e. show the system and what you want to do precisely.

The equations themselves are quite lengthy, so I'm trying to avoid dealing with them here. I'll try to elaborate more.
Using state feedback, the input shall be $u=-\textbf{Kx}$. Given stable allocated poles, this makes $\textbf{x}$ tend to $\textbf{0}$ as a whole, given enough time. What I'm looking for is a way to determine $\textbf{K}$ in a way that I still can use pole placement, but some certain states in $\textbf{x}$ won't tend to 0 and only assist in converging the remaining parts of the state, not converging to any specific reference signal.

I'm guessing LQ optimal control can achieve something similar, when the tunable weights corresponding to the "uncontrolled" states are set to 0. However the transient behaviour is much more "abstractly" related to the weight matrices and so are more difficult to tune for a desired transient behaviour.
